# Cannot get next results set when calling db2 stored procedure using php from Debian container to IBMi server

Tags: php, stored-procedures, db2, websphere

I am trying to call a db2 stored procedure using php (ibm_db2 v2.0.2 extension) from my Debian container to IBMi server.

I have installed ibm_db2 (v2.0.2) php extension on Debian container (docker) to request against a db2 database which is hosted on an IBMi server through TCP/IP protocol and it works just fine and I can make queries correctly.

My issue arise when I try to call a stored procedure with multiple results sets.
When I call a stored procedure, I am able to get the first results set using db2_fetch_assoc function but I cannot get the next results sets with db2_next_result function. There is no error thrown, the db2_fetch_assoc simply return false for the next results sets as if there was no subsequent sets.

The app calling theses stored procedure is deployed on an ZendServer on IBMi and everything works perfectly. The problem arise on my "docker" environment. 
I tried many things like changing the version of ibm_db2 extension, trying another ODBC driver version, changing php configuration but I can't get it working.

The odd things is that when I run the stored procedure with db2 cli from my docker, I am able to get all my results sets correctly. It just doesn't work with php.

Coming to have some help. Did someone run into the same issue?

Thanks a lot,

EDIT 03/18/2020

[Drivers info from db2_client_info php function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Sap.png)

This is my code to retrieve my results sets:

```
while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
  print_r($row);
}

while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc(db2_next_result($statement))) {
 print_r($row);
}

while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc(db2_next_result($statement))) {
 print_r($row);
}
```

EDIT 03/18/2020 10:50

The php version is 7.1

The code now look like follow:

```
try {
   db2_execute($statement);
   while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($statement)) {
     print_r($row);
   }

   $nextResults = db2_next_result($statement);
   while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($nextResults)) {
    print_r($row);
   }

   $nextResults = db2_next_result($statement);
   while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($nextResults)) {
    print_r($row);
   }      
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hello @mao, thanks for the quick reply. I added the elements you've requested. I don't know yet how to get my db2 drivers infos from CLI so I the meanwhile I added the infos returned by db2_client_info php function.

Comment: @mao, I updated the code as requested and provided php version (7.1).

Comment: if you look at file `ibm_db2.c` source code for `db2_next_result` function you should be able to match its actions to the CLI trace . Ensure you have allocated enough memory for the container to store the result-sets.

Comment: @mao, $nextResults is a resource and no exceptions are thrown. But the $row = db2_fetch_assoc($nextResults), $row is a boolean and is false.  How can I activate the trace? Do you have any example of the trace command I could run. Should I run in on my client or my server?

Comment: I check this and keep you posted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @mao, Thank you for the trace idea. I could find some insight from the output.
I'm not familiar with the syntax but it seems that an error occurs on my 2nd db2_next_result() with the following error message: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0125E  Function sequence error. SQLSTATE=HY010.
And then when it performs the 3rd db_next_result() it says SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND.
I am interested in the 3rd results sets and I guess that the error of the 2nd affects the 3rd which says SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND.
By the way the 2nd result sets doesn't return any data but only the 1st and the 3rd should.

Comment: Please *conditionally*  call db2_fetch... (by testing $nextResults), as shown in the IBM documentation here  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023500.html   , and additionally use a separate variable per result-set,  and *ensure your container* has sufficient ram allocated.

Comment: It worked. Following the IBM syntax fixed it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per comment thread, the symptom was caused by incorrect coding.

For the `db2_fetch_*` calls to work, the preceding `db2_next_result` must return a result-set and you have to test for that.

In your original code you were unconditionally calling the `db2_fetch_assoc` with an invalid argument, as the `db2_next_result` did not return a result-set.

As per the code in both the [IBM example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/c0008936.html), and in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-next-result.php), it is necessary to test the result of `db2_next_result` before calling any fetch action on.

The [CLI trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.trb.doc/doc/c0008936.html) showed a function sequence error, which tells you that the function is being called in the wrong circumstances.